# S = 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 ... 1/n

Tags: python, math

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
while i != n:
    if i>n:
        print(S)
    else:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            S -= 1 / i
            i += 1

        else:
            S += 1 / i
            i += 1

print(S)
```

I need to solve S = 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 ... 1/n, but when I enter n as 5, the output should be 0.783, instead it prints 0.583

Comment: I suggest that you add `print()` statements to see what is happening in your code. For more tips on debugging, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: In your own words, what does `while i != n:` mean? When you give `5` as the value of `n`, do you think that the code inside the loop will ever use `5` as a value for `i`? Why or why not? Did you try to *test* this, for example by `print(i)`? Also: did you notice a *pattern* behind the incorrect results? For example: does it not strike you as interesting that the output you get for `n` equal to `5` is in fact the *correct* output for `n` equal to `4`?

Comment: what is the answer supposed to be when `n=4`?

Comment: When I copy your code and try to run it, I get "name 'i' is not defined". Be sure that when you post code here to ask a question that it doesn't cause errors other than what you are asking about.

Comment: I'm sorry. Didn't realize that n=5 is actually the answer to 4 and I had to check it once more for n instead of ending the while loop.

Comment: Another way is to create a generator over the series `(1/(i+1))*(-1)**i` where `i ranges from 0 to n` and then compute the sum. Check my answer for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slighter cleaner version:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
S = 0

for j in range(1,n+1):
    if j % 2 == 0:
        S -= 1/j
    else:
        S += 1/j
    # print(j)
    # print(S)

print(S)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more pythonic way to solve this, by first creating a generator with your series, and then using `sum()`.

Your series is of the following form -

[image]

Steps needed:

1. Create a generator for the above form
2. Use summation over the generator from `i: 0 -> n`

```
n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
S = sum((1/(i+1))*(-1)**i for i in range(n))
print(S)
```

```
Enter a number: 5
0.7833333333333332
```

---

#### Plotting the function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#In function form
def f(n): return sum((1/(i+1))*(-1)**i for i in range(n))

#Plotting
y = [f(i+1) for i in range(100)]
plt.plot(y)
```

[image]

Comment: Or `sum(s / k for s,k in zip(cycle([1,-1]), range(1,n)))` with `from itertools import cycle`

Comment: definitely, multiple ways to do the generator! love the use of `itertools.cycle` its my fav library so great to see an interesting use for the `cycle` method.